# JS hide email function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took the code below from a wider document, and tried to include it between 2 script tags, but for some reason it's not working (nothing happens).
Do I need to add some document ready syntax or something like this?
Thanks,

```
<script>
function sendAnnotatedMailTo(name, company, domain, subject, body) {
    locationstring = 'mai' + 'lto:' + name + '@' + company + '.' + domain + "?subject=" + escape(subject) + "&body=" + escape(body);
    window.location.replace(locationstring);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You just defined a function, in order to let the actual code work, you would need to call this function

Comment: Thanks. How do I do this? (I'm not familial with JS - yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only defined a function but didn't call it.

You have to call your function like this:

```
<a href="javascript:sendAnnotatedMailTo('name', 'democompany', 'domain.tld', 'Subject of mail', 'Body of mail')">Send mail</a>
```

This will open your mail client and prepare an email to name@democompany.domain.tld with the subject "Subject of mail" and the bodytext "Body of mail".

Btw: You shouldn't use the deprecated JS function "escape" anymore. Use encodeURI instead:

```
<script>
    function sendAnnotatedMailTo(name, company, domain, subject, body) {
        locationstring = 'mai' + 'lto:' + name + '@' + company + '.' + domain + "?subject=" + encodeURI(subject) + "&body=" + encodeURI(body);
        window.location.replace(locationstring);
    }
</script>
```